# How to annotate/use composite partition key in Cassandra in java?

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I know I can use partition key by annotating     @PartitionKey when partition key is simple (made of one column).
How can I do the same if partition key is composite.

I couldn't find anything for this on datastax documentation and google was of no help as well.

Comment: Probably I can use accessor to do the task , I was just wandering if we can do that with Mapper as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example with one column:

```
@PartitionKey
private UUID userId;
```

And with a composite key:

```
@PartitionKey(0)
private int pk1;

@PartitionKey(1)
private int pk2;
```